# Misterious invoking remote EJB3 on WAS 7

Tags: ejb-3.0, websphere-7

i apology about my english.

I am trying with EJB 3 technology. I have two ears applications, one of them is a web application and the other one is an application with remote EJBs, using EJB 3.0. I deploy them in the same server, Websphere 7, and they start succesfully. My test is invoking EJBs through @EJB annotation and through "lookup", then, the web application has a Servlet with a reference at EJB through @EJB annotation, and other reference at remote interface, i.e.

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
import org.icabanas.pruebaconcepto.dominio.Producto;  
import org.icabanas.pruebaconcepto.facade.ProductoSessionFacade;  

public class ProductoServlet extends HttpServlet {  

    @EJB(name="EJB/ProductoSessionFacade")  
    private ProductoSessionFacade productoSessionFacade;  

    private ProductoSessionFacade productoSessionFacadeJndi;      

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
        Producto producto = getProductoFromRequest(req);  

        try{  
            System.out.println("INJECTION");  
            productoSessionFacade.alta(producto);  
        }  
        catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println("Error in INJECTION");  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
        }  

        try{  
            System.out.println("JNDI");           
            productoSessionFacadeJndi = (ProductoSessionFacade) lookupJNDI("org.icabanas.pruebaconcepto.facade.ProductoSessionFacade");  
            productoSessionFacadeJndi.alta(producto);  
        }  
        catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println("Error in JNDI");  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
        }  
    }  
.......  
}
```

I have the following problem: When i start the applications all works fine, i get the EJB annoted and through jndi lookup, but when i restart or republish the ear containing web application, i get the EJB annonted and it works fine, but when i try to get the EJB through JNDI lookup i get the following error:

"org.icabanas.pruebaconcepto.facade._ProductoSessionFacade_Stub incompatible with org.icabanas.pruebaconcepto.facade.ProductoSessionFacade"

Any idea about what happen?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Please include the exception stack trace.  It appears that you're missing a call to PortableRemoteObject.narrow, but it's not clear whether you or the server forgot to do it.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a bug in WebSphere 7 that was fixed in 7.0.0.17 I think. I had the same issue with 7.0.0.15. A workaround is to also restart the application that contains the EJB.